# Stop iTunes/Spotify Music when returning to App

Tags: objective-c, ios

Im having some trouble finding information on this. I would like to know how to stop the itunes/spotify or any other music players music upon returning to my application. They currently both play the same time.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
if ([[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
  [[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] stop];
}
```

Don't forget: You need to add `MediaPlayer.framework` to your target and in your `AppDelegate.m` import `MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h`.

Also take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

**EDIT**

I found a better solution than mine in Apples Audio Session Programming Guide: [Checking if Other Audio is Playing During App Launch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW56)

**EDIT 2**

Code sample …

Comment: Hi thanks, good find!

This doesnt tell me how to interupt that particular music though?

Comment: I edited the code above :) Please accept the answer if it helped you.